# UI not working after DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, dispatcher, dispatchertimer

After implementing `DispatcherTimer`, my application that involves user interaction do not work. For more information, I am trying to develop an application using leap motion. Need the timer work together with the UI for user to make some gestures and stop after timer ends, but now the leap motion no longer detect any gesture after using dispatcher timer. Some advice please thanks!

My code for timer:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (time > 0)
    {
        if (time <= 10)
        {
            if (time % 2 == 0)
            {
                TBCountdown.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                TBCountdown.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            }
            time--;
            TBCountdown.Text = string.Format("00:0{0}:0{1}", time / 60, time % 60);
        }
        else
        {
            time--;
            TBCountdown.Text = string.Format("00:0{0}:{1}", time / 60, time % 60);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Completed");
    }
}
```

Comment: When the application becomes unresponsive, you should be able to pause it in Visual Studio and see which code is executing. Can you edit your question to include this information? I see nothing obviously wrong with what you've posted. (You only need to initialize `dispatcherTimer` once, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions. 
Dan Puzey was right, it is designed to work with WPF UI in a responsive way. 
It only lags a lil sometimes, but overall it should still respond.
Hopefully it doesn't hangs anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I beleive the Dispatacher is running on the same UI thread aand hecne making UI unresponsive. A better way is to use BackgroundWorker to do time consuming tasks on background thread.

Comment: The `Dispatcher` and `DispatcherTimer` classes are designed to work with WPF UI in a responsive way. There is no time consuming task running on a foreground thread here.